# Is it said in hinduism that food served before an individual should not be consumed with more delay?

Tags: scripture, food

Many parents complain that food should not be taken with more delay. This may be told as of a reason that **"annam parabrahma swaroopam"** and delaying the food by engaging in other activities is like insulting goddess Annapurna. Also say that while consuming food, one should not involve in any other activities.

Delay in this question refers to an assumption that the food is already served and the individual although arrived to eat, letting the food to wait in plate without consuming it.

My question is, are there any references which provide explicitly about that same.

Answer (score 6):

> Also say that while consuming food, one should not involve in any
> other activities.

Yes, one must not speak while eating. This is mentioned in scriptures:

> [While passing] excreta, [holding] sexual intercourse, [making] Homa,
> cleansing the teeth, bathing, taking meals, and making adorations, one
> should always abstain from speaking at all. (316)
>
> He, who, always abstaining from speech, takes his meals for full one
> year, lives gloriously in the celestial region for a thousand Koti
> Yugas. (317)
>
> *Atri Smriti/Samhita*

The following verse from Chapter 1 of the Usana Smriti is also relevant:

> He should daily adore his food and take it without speaking ill of it
> ; on seeing it, **he should be delighted and happy, and should welcome
> it with laudation. (60)**

IMO, the bold portion above is implicitly suggesting that one must not delay in eating once the food has being served.